# Kendo UI - Binding directly to EF object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, grid, kendo-ui

I'm considering buying Kendo UI package from Telerik. But when I take a look on their demo of the Grid control, it always shown that they bind the grid to ViewModel object. I know that when converting EF object to Json object, sometimes we will get circular reference error. I can get around it by setting db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; I have tried with SlickGrid was success. I wonder if anyone have been able to bind Kendo UI grid directly to EF object?

Answer (score 0):

You can put [ScriptIgnoreAttribute] attribute on the properties that are causing circular dependencies. I would recommend you use a view-model-specific object with only the information you need. That should reduce the database data size that is returned from the database.

I don't know if there is a problem with this from your comment but Telerik says to use view model objects. [Telerik Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-avoid-circular-reference-exceptions)

Comment: You mean [ScriptIgnore]? I have seen it from some post on StackOverFlow, however, I still get circular reference error. While setting ProxyCreatingEnabled = false works.

Comment: I am pretty sure the your right so I change the Attribute in my post. I don't know why you are having the problem.

Comment: I wonder if there is any different between [ScriptIgnoreAttribute] and [[ScriptIgnore] ? I tried both and neither one of them work

Comment: There is not any difference, .net framework allows you to omit the Attribute while defining it on your classes, methods, properties, etc..

Comment: Then I think it won't work with Slick Grid as I still get Circular Reference error on it.